# Nginx accessing multiple domains with IP without default server/conf

Tags: nginx, server, ip, domain-name

Accessing a website on a Nginx server with IP address on which multiple domain names/websites/apps are served and there is no default server/conf, will open the first alphabetical domain on that IP.

Is this TRUE or FALSE?

And can this be somehow overwritten if TRUE?

Comment: False. If the IP is passed to Nginx instead of a domain name, it will fall to the default server block. If no default server block is specified, it will fall to the first matching block in your configuration. In short, you should always specify a default server block.

Comment: Yeah, i don't have a default server block....this quote is what i'm interested about: "it will fall to the first matching block" which one is the first???? i think it goes alphabetically

Comment: Ah, I see... Good point. I would suggest you specify a default server block. For a bit more clarification, see [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

False. Because depended on your config.

> During searching for a virtual server by name, if the name matches
>   more than one of the specified variants, (e.g. both a wildcard name
>   and regular expression match), the first matching variant will be
>   chosen, in the following order of priority:
>
> 1. the exact name
> 2. the longest wildcard name starting with an asterisk, e.g.
>      “*.example.com”
> 3. the longest wildcard name ending with an asterisk, e.g. “mail.*”
> 4. the first matching regular expression (in order of appearance in the
>      configuration file)

If no match found, then nginx will route the request to the default server for this port. **Default server is the first one** in your config file — which is nginx’s standard default behavior. If all servers included using `include` directive with mask - included files sorted alphabetically (by name of file, not name of domain in server_name).

Default server can also be set explicitly which server should be default, with the `default_server` parameter in the `listen` directive.

Also, you can add `server_name` with IP as name, if you need different behaviors for access server via IP and via unknown domain name.

UPD: In case of accessing nginx via IP - hostname will be equal to IP. So, nginx will start to find server_name which match IP host name. All that described above still valid.

Comment: Sorry but you named all the facts like if i want to access the server with domain name (such as: domain_name.com) but i want to access it with IP address....it is all local and that is the reason why i can't get it with domain name....i know all the options how to get it...(i could edit a hosts file and put the domain name and IP, i could make this domain name as single domain on this server or i could set it as a default server) but the question remains: If you access a server with IP 192.168.0.50 which domain is going to be opened if there are more than one and there is no default

Comment: Access via IP same as access via domain name. I this case host name will be equal to IP. So, nginx will start to find server_name which match 192.168.0.50 host name. Behavior of nginx in case of no server_name matched - described in my answer :)

Comment: Too much written....only this is important: if server is accessed via ip and no default server is configured then all domain configuration are "sorted alphabetically (by name of file, not name of domain in server_name)"

Comment: Just hint: this is correct only if _ALL_ server blocks included via _ONE_ `include *`. You also asked how to change this behavior, that's why so much text :)